# Pages recovered from trash not showing in Pages menu but do show on website

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am using Apostrophe CMS with the Workflow module. It's always been a bit buggy when it comes to moving things around but this one has me stumped.

See attached image. Originally, I had a folder named "Atoms". There were multiple subpages under Atoms. I mistakenly moved the Atoms folder to the Trash. No big deal, just recover from the Trash, right? Well, when I recovered, I have the Atoms folder back in the menu but the subpages no longer appear. They do however appear on the website. I've looked in every Trash folder. The pages are nowhere to be found.

To summarize, after recovering a folder from the Trash, the subpages of that folder are no longer visible in the admin area but are visible on the website.

I'm hopeful that someone has run into this before. The pages have a LOT of content that would take a tremendous amount of time to re-create.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is resolved in the version 2.106.3 release. https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/2194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved in the version 2.106.3 release. github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/2194